# Store 500g dry yeast package after opened

Tags: yeast, storage

I bought a 500g S-05 package and i'm planning to use it only 20 g per week. Any advices on how to store it? it will last around 4-5 months

Comment: Some information here: https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/408/how-long-can-yeast-be-stored/16421#16421

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a half kilo pack of US-05 in the freezer for about 2 years, and it was always fine. Just seal it up as best as you can between uses.

Answer (score 2):

You should be good with an airtight container in a fridge. I had dried bread yeast for a couple of years in an airtight container in the fridge, and it was usable until it was exhausted. You should certainly be good for a half year.

Answer (score 0):

Your 500g pack will have a best before date, usually about two years after purchase date. Once you open the pack, transfer the contents to a similar sized plastic food container with a sealed lid, and store in your refrigerator. Mark the container lid with the expiry date. My experience is that your yeast will last at least one year beyond that expiry date.